# Ansible unable to connect to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, ansible, amazon-ec2, codeship

I'm trying to use Ansible to connect to an AWS EC2 instance from a Codeship build. This has been working perfectly in another AWS region (eu-west-1) but now I want to setup servers in us-east-1 and I'm getting the following error:

```
<ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461915330.37-230126286487108 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461915330.37-230126286487108 )" )'
fatal: [ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:\nOpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

debug1: Reading configuration data /home/rof/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket \"/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user\" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com [52.1.39.45] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load \"/home/rof/.ssh/id_rsa\" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rof/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com\" from file \"/dev/null\"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA f6:db:c0:15:19:17:45:cc:db:6f:16:f4:6f:02:bf:79
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com\" from file \"/dev/null\"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"52.1.39.45\" from file \"/dev/null\"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com,52.1.39.45' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/rof/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fbfa369ea30),
debug2: key: /home/rof/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/rof/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/rof/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/rof/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/rof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 6a:73:a4:d1:c5:79:9d:6b:6f:3f:7d:cd:8e:60:97:84
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 6a:73:a4:d1:c5:79:9d:6b:6f:3f:7d:cd:8e:60:97:84
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com ([52.1.39.45]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user.WpJOoaH4MuX8djA0
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user]
debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 4
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process
debug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 8248
Control socket connect(/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user): Connection refused
Failed to connect to new control master
", "unreachable": true}
```

I am able to connect with a simple ssh command like this `ssh ec2-user@ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com` so I'm pretty sure the ssh keys are setup correctly. The only difference is the region and the AMI, but the AMI is Amazon Linux in both cases.

Can someone tell me the problem or point me in the right direction please.

Comment: the authentication seems correct (you get "Authenticated to ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com"). Can you run the command locally on the ec2 instance itself to debug? Any chance you did a pre-config step on eu-west-1 that you forgot on us-east-1?

Comment: Yes I can execute this command on the ec2 instance `( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461915330.37-230126286487108 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461915330.37-230126286487108 )" )` And I'm sure I did not do any other steps before.

Comment: When I run the entire ssh command `ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt ec2-52-1-39-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461915330.37-230126286487108 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461915330.37-230126286487108 )" )'` I get another error

Comment: `debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-52-1-39-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com ([52.1.39.45]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-52-1-39-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user.gSeT6lu2qkM9OpjJ
muxserver_listen bind(): No such file or directory`

Comment: well the IP address of your us-east-1 instance seems to be 52.1.39.45, but the control socket is looking for "/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-**52-11-9-45**.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user" . is this not the IP of your eu-west-1 instance?

Comment: No, sorry I changed the IP address.

Comment: So as "/home/rof/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-52-11-9-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com-22-ec2-user\" does not exist, isn't this your problem? shouldn't you change this to your actual IP?

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to connect to new control master

means you've problem using control connections (connecting to your control socket file). Check the permissions or remove the socket file and try again.

Normally these settings are in your `~/.ssh/config`, so either disable it (`ControlMaster no`) or change the path (e.g. `ControlPath /tmp` or check this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295849/21471)).

Since you're using Ansible, you can disable control connections in your `ansible.cfg` (e.g. `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`):

```
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no
```

as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33347112/55075). Or try disabling `accelerate` if enabled (as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668998/55075)):

```
accelerate: false
```

And try again.